# How to get the focus of an object right

Tags: objects, camera

I do not manage to get the focus right in this image. The focus should be on the left white pillow, which has a subtle grey line on it. I have selected it as the focus object for the camera, but somehow it is not sharp, actually nothing seems sharp. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Can someone please help?

- The render image is in Cycles, 1 Frame, 1500 samples, no treshold, no timelimit. denoise on, exposure 3.0. I tried also 1700 samples, which did not make a difference.
- The camera setting is 50 mm, 4.5 F-stop, focus object left white pillow.

[image: unfocused render]

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the camera focuses on the object's origin, not the object as a whole. It would be probably better to use an empty object as the focus target and place that where you want the focus to be. Also there are some render settings that will make any render not as sharp as you might want: like having not enough samples will lead the denoising to smear everything, or too much [Pixel Filtering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/film.html#pixel-filter).

Comment: @L0Lock thank you very much for your tip! The empty object actually works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, the camera focuses on the object's origin, not the object as a whole.
Hence, it would be probably better to use an empty object as the focus target and place that where you want the focus to be.

Also, there are some render settings that will make any render not as sharp as you might want, like not having enough [samples](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html) will lead the denoising to smear everything, or too much [Pixel Filtering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/film.html#pixel-filter) will effectively blur the image.